# Kotlin: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning

Tags: java, kotlin

My Kotlin code is running well, though I'm getting this warning:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

How can I fix this?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10; VS Code with the following installed:
Kotlin Command line Kotlin compiler
openjdk 18.0.2-ea 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-2, mixed mode, sharing)

I tried renaming the .kt files with underscores but nothing changed.

[image: First screenshot showing the issue]

[image: Second screenshot]

[image: Third screenshot]

[image: The last screenshot]

Comment: Is the warning is displayed during compilation or during the run ? Can you share the command line to execute the program ?

Comment: This file Write_your_first_program_in_Kotlin.kt executed well, but still with the same warning. And now this file Create_a_birthday_message_in_Kotlin.kt is not executing.

Comment: Which version of kotlin are you using?

Comment: Based on the [Kotlin 1.5.x change log](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/docs/changelogs/ChangeLog-1.5.X.md), I'd say he is using earlier than Kotlin 1.5.0.  This sound like issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44232.  And the fix will be to upgrade Kotlin.